# What is a proper way to handle AdaptiveCard action using DirectLine?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, adaptive-cards

What is a proper way to handle AdaptiveCard action on the client side using DirectLine? Should I build `"value"` for activity by hand?

If so, I realized that multi-select's value is handled in different way for different channels (BotFrameworkEmulator sends the values separated with commas while WebChat uses semicolons). Which format should I pick? Isn't this inconsistency a bug?

Comment: what do you mean build the Value by hand??

Comment: Activity has various properties. I've seen that when adaptive card data is posted back from WebChat it goes under `"value"` property. So the question is if I should build the `"value"` object on my own knowing the ids of inputs on the card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Emulator is in a sense a form of WebChat. I don't think the inconsistency is a bug, but if you see WebChat in different places then it's likely to be different versions and may therefore have different behavior.

Fortunately your bot code is free to interpret the received values however you want it to. If your bot is likely to run on multiple channels then you may want to make your bot smart enough to account for multiple possible choice-separators. Otherwise you can just make sure your bot is looking for the right separator for the channel you want to run it on.

As far as I can tell commas are the more standard up-to-date separators, so it's probably best to go with those. But if you're making your own Direct Line client then it's ultimately up to you how you format the activities that your client sends to the bot.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the inconsistency is not a bug, it is just the way the data is sent back by different channels. Please remember, Adaptive cards are a fairly new concept of exchanging data between the user and the bot code. It is still going to take time how the values are rendered and posted by each channel to come to a common format. That being said, I would not over think this problem much.
The design pattern for the bot should always be made *after fixing the channels* that the bot will be published on. Once the channels are fixed then it would just be matter of coding to handle the various ways in which the post back data is sent back to the bot